# Add 3 bits to 5 bits

Tags: digital-logic

I want to add a 3-bit and a 5-bit number preferably using 4-bit full adder. The 5 bit number only has these 5 possibilities (multiples of 7):
00000
00111
01110
10101
11100
and 3-bits (1-5):
001
010
011
100
101

What is the most hardware efficient solution (minimum no. of ICs)?

Comment: What does your K-map tell you?

Comment: haven't kmapped it but a solution i can think of is a half adder with 5th bit and carry out  after adding LS 4bits. This i think is better than what a kmap would give me, i just wanted to know if there was a better way because the bits are not "general".

Comment: The K-map is 85% DNC. That usually leads to more compact solutions than brute force.

Comment: `bits are not "general"` ... what does this mean?

Comment: Your question doesn't state consistent goals. You say you want the "most hardware efficient" solution but you also say that you would prefer using a 4-bit full adder. Since the addends have a limited set of possible values a generic adder may not be the most "hardware efficient" solution. Also, how do you measure "efficiency"...number of chips? number of gates? delay time? power consumption?

Comment: @jsotola - i mean that there are only a limited set of possible input values.

Comment: minimum number of ICs ... one 256 byte rom

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use gates the way to go is to use a Karnaugh Map to find the minimal solution possible.

If you want to use only 1 IC you can replace all the logic with a 256 byte ROM, here is a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA12Z7gQ4P0) explaining the process.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest using 4 bit full adder and a dual 4:1 mux:

You get the lower 4 bits (bit0 to bit3) using the adder , 3-bit number and lower 4 bit from the 5-bit number.

For bit5 and bit6 use the fifth bit form the 5-bit number and carry bit from the adder.

The output B5 is B5in xor CY

The output B6 is B5in and Cy

Actually is an one bit adder with carry

The implementation with a dual 4:1 mux

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLMFP5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>